# Google Sheets Copy row if value is X. Remove Blank Spaces.

Tags: google-sheets, copy

Currently I am making a spreadsheet for ordering and receiving in my stores. 
I'm using a form(IMG1) to get the information and I am trying to condense it into another sheet for easier viewing and such.(IMG2)
We have three stores that I am trying to separate data. 
Whenever we get a new response I would like to have the stores sorted to their own sheet, bringing other cells in the row with it(although I am copying the data from another sheet with my current formula. 
[image: This is where I am getting my data from.]

[image: This is the formula I have]

[image: Showing all of the spaces]
using`=arrayformula(IF('Form Responses 1'!J2:J= "Oregon City",'Responses Simplified'!A:I,))` works for the most part for the first chunk. My only issue is that it will include all of the empty spaces of the items that do not match. So when I go down to where Beaverton is(IMG3), it is a bunch of empty spots. 
I am not proficient enough to get the final piece to the puzzle, I got far with google but now I either don't know what search terms to use or I'm missing something.
So I am asking if anybody has a more elegant solution or if they know how to remove the blank spots without giving me a REF issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your formula in query and excluding blanks like this:

```
=query(arrayformula(if('Form Responses 1'!J2:J="Beaverton",'Responses Simplified'!A:I,"")),"Select * where Col1<>''")
```

Comment: This is working much, much better! Thank you! Did a few more small tweaks due to it showing the line above what it should. my final code looks as such `=query(arrayformula(if('Responses Simplified'!A:A="Beaverton",'Responses Simplified'!A:I,"")),"Select * where Col1<>''")` 
I still have ONE blank line at the top of the sheet but nothing I cannot hide! My sheet functions as intended! 
I am curious what the function of "`"Select * where Col1<>''"`" actually does. Thanks again

Comment: It is the query. Select * selects all (returned from your arrayformua where Col1 (the first column returned (A) is not blank. Maybe another column would work better for you?

Comment: Cool! thanks for taking time to explain it. I always like knowing the syntax and what the process is doing. 
I will try different columns and see what I come up with, but I am satisfied with the result thus far.